# Mysql query to convert two columns to one row (select default values)

Tags: mysql

I want to select default values from **any** table.
I want make method for get all default values from any table for using in auto generated form or etc.

So Im created this query:

```
SELECT `COLUMN_NAME`,`COLUMN_DEFAULT` FROM information_schema.`COLUMNS` WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='databasename' AND `TABLE_NAME`='tablename' LIMIT 1
```

The result is simple

```
| SELECT  | COLUMN_DEFAULT |
+---------+----------------+
| id      | null           |
| name    | 'defname'      |
| content | 'defcontent'   |
```

I need to convert it to like this

```
| id   | name    | content   |
+------+---------+-----------+
| null | defname | decontent |
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?  What is the underlying business problem that you are trying to solve?  Sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) to me.

Comment: Is not necessary convert nothing, just use some like this "SELECT id, name, content FROM databasename" or SELECT * .. a simply query.

Comment: check this [select * transform row value as table column name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14765765/select-transform-row-value-as-table-column-name)

Comment: I want make method for get all default values from any table for using in auto generated form or etc.

Comment: So what's wrong with the recordset provided by your existing query?

Comment: I think the best way is to pivot his table on the application side not using SQL because in this case you need to use a dynamic SQL.

Comment: Ok. Now I change it in application side, sou I safe it as is.

Answer (score 0):

Single straight forward SQL statement can't be achieved here as the number columns for different tables may vary.

I would suggest to define a stored procedure to identify the defined columns of the table in question and generate the pivot table based on those names and values.

Following `stored procedure` helps you do the same.

```
delimiter //
drop procedure if exists default_values //

create procedure default_values( in db varchar(255), in tbl varchar(255) )
begin
  declare c_name varchar(255) default '';
  declare all_names_read boolean default false;

  declare c_names cursor for 
    select column_name from information_schema.columns
      where table_schema=db and table_name=tbl;
  declare continue handler for not found 
  -- declare continue handler for SQLSTATE '02000' 
    set all_names_read = true;

  set @sql_query = '\nselect';
  set @rowNumber = 0;

  open c_names;
  repeat
    fetch c_names into c_name;

    set @sql_query = 
          concat( @sql_query, 
                  if( all_names_read, '\n', if( @rowNumber < 1, '\n', ',\n' ) )
                 );

    if( ! all_names_read ) then
      set @rowNumber = @rowNumber + 1;

      set @sql_query = 
            concat( @sql_query, '    max( case column_name when \'',
                    c_name, '\' then column_default end ) as \'',
                    c_name, '\'' );
    end if;

    until all_names_read
  end repeat;

  close c_names;

  set @sql_query =
        concat( @sql_query,
                'from information_schema.columns\n',
                'where table_schema=? and table_name=?' );
  set @db_name = db;
  set @tbl_name = tbl;

  prepare stmt from @sql_query;
  execute stmt using @db_name, @tbl_name;
  -- execute stmt;
  deallocate prepare stmt;
end;
//

delimiter ;
```

Following is a test on the stored procedure defined.

```
mysql> create table test.tide
    -> ( t timestamp, i int default 9, d date, e enum( 'yes', 'no' ) default 'no' );

mysql> desc test.tide;
+-------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+------...
| Field | Type             | Null | Key | Default           | Extra...
+-------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+------...
| t     | timestamp        | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on up...
| i     | int(11)          | YES  |     | 9                 |         
| d     | date             | YES  |     | NULL              |         
| e     | enum('yes','no') | YES  |     | no                |         
+-------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+------...
4 rows in set (0.02 sec)

mysql> call default_values( 'test', 'tide' );
+-------------------+------+------+------+
| t                 | i    | d    | e    |
+-------------------+------+------+------+
| CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | 9    | NULL | no   |
+-------------------+------+------+------+
```

Above result was on executing the generated query by stored procedure.
Generated query was this:

```
mysql> select @sql_query\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
@sql_query:
select
    max( case column_name when 't' then column_default end ) as 't',
    max( case column_name when 'i' then column_default end ) as 'i',
    max( case column_name when 'd' then column_default end ) as 'd',
    max( case column_name when 'e' then column_default end ) as 'e'
from information_schema.columns
where table_schema=? and table_name=?
```